# third time i execute a function then runtime error occur C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<string.h>

struct node
{
    char *word;
    char *meaning;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
    struct node *parent;
}*root=NULL,*trav,*tmp;

void add()
{
    int res;
    // create node
    tmp=(struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp->word=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    tmp->meaning=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("\nEnter Word\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",tmp->word);
    printf("Enter Meaning\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c",tmp->meaning);
    tmp->left=NULL;
    tmp->right=NULL;
        trav=root;
        while(1)
        {

            if(trav==NULL)
            {
                root=tmp;
                root->parent=NULL;
                root->left=NULL;
                root->right=NULL;
                break;

            }
            else
            {
                res=strcmp(tmp->word,trav->word);
                // if res==0 then words are same
                // if res==1 then left word is alphabetically smaller
                // if res==2 then left word is alphabetically bigger
                if(res<0)
                {   
                    if(trav->left==NULL)
                    {
                        trav->left=tmp;
                        tmp->parent=trav;
                        break;
                    }
                    //goto left child

                    trav=trav->left;

                }
                else if(res>0)
                {   
                    if(trav->right==NULL)
                    {
                        trav->right=tmp;
                        tmp->parent=trav;
                        break;
                    }
                    //goto left child
                    trav=trav->right;

                }
                if(res==0)
                {
                    printf("Word already exist\n");
                    break;
                }


            }

        }
}




int main()
{

    int flag=0;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n1.add word\n2.delete word\n3.search word\n4.inorder traverse\n5.preorder traverse\n6.postorder traverse\n7.exit\n");
        switch(getche())
        {
        case '1':
            {
                add();
                 break;
            }
        case '2':
            {
                delete_word();
                break;
            }
        case '3':
            {
                search();
                break;
            }
        case '4':
            {
                traverse_inorder(root);
                break;
            }
        case '5':
            {
                traverse_preorder(root);
                break;
            }
        case '6':
            {
                traverse_postorder(root);
                break;
            }
        case '7':
            flag=1;
        }

        if(flag==1)
            break;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

/*
    I am create a dictionary based on tree, when i execute add function on third time, then runtime error came, please help me*/
/* That error came on the malloc function, when it encounter on third time then program goes close*/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating only one character here:

```
tmp->word=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
tmp->meaning=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

So, after that you're trying to write a character string to a memory block that has a size too small for keeping the value. This causes a memory corruption.

Guess you want to allocate an array, so you need:

```
tmp->word=malloc(len * sizeof(char));
tmp->meaning=malloc(len * sizeof(char));
```

Here `len` is the maximum supposed length of the `word` and `meaning` including terminating `\0`.

Comment: thou shalt not cast the return value of `malloc()`

Comment: @Aniket yes, it is not necessary.

Comment: @Aniket edited. Can you explain why it is dangerous? (not talking about forgotten stdlib.h)

Comment: what if I say `tmp->word = (int *)malloc(sizeof(char));` ? - by mistake if you will...

Comment: @Aniket well, pointer are dangerous (anyway). If you use them, you have to do care about what you're writing.
Essentially, IMHO it is a mistake of the same level as forgotten `malloc()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are only allocating one character for `word` and `meaning`, and then reading > 1 character into them (i.e. writing into unallocated memory)